# css: how to change table size when use display:table?

Tags: html, css

CSS

```
<style>
.featuresContainer { display: table; }
.featuresContent { display: table-row; }
.contentLeft {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 50%;
    background-color: red;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding: 7px;
}

.contentRight {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 50%;
    background-color: blue;
    padding: 7px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
</style>
```

Html:

```
<div class="featuresContainer">
    <div class="featuresContent">
        <div class="contentLeft">
            <h3>Assignments Tool</h3>
            <ul>
                <li>Any type of assignment or assessment</li>
                <li>Quizzes</li>
                <li>Tests</li>
                <li>Polls</li>
                <li>Discussion Forum with tone meter</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="contentRight">
            <img src="https://sandbox.velop.org/styles/default/velop/images/assingments_tool.png" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="featuresContent">
        <div class="contentLeft">
            <img src="https://sandbox.velop.org/styles/default/velop/images/web_tool.png" />           
        </div>
        <div class="contentRight">
            <h3>Web Tool</h3>
            <ul>
                <li>Web link</li>
                <li>Any RSS feed</li>
                <li>Youtube and Vimeo integration and tracking</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Question:

How to change the size of table? I want table only to be the half width of the entire page. I tried `.featuresContainer { display: table; width:50%;}` But it does not work.

Comment: Did you tried with .featuresContainer { display: table; width:50px;} or maybe { display: table-cell; width: 50%; }

Comment: [Like this](http://jsbin.com/IvEREHi/2/edit) ?

Answer (score 0):

use `table-layout: fixed;` like this:

```
.featuresContainer { display: table; width:50%; table-layout: fixed;}
```